# Time complexity of the inner loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

Can someone help me with calculating the time complexity of the inner loop? As far as I understand, the outer one will be O(n). But I have no idea how to calculate what happens inside the second one.

```
for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 2; i * j < n; j++) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every iteration of "outer loop", inner loop runs `n/i` times

So, total complexity of this will be given by:

```
n/2 + n/3 + n/4 + ...
= n * (1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ...)
```

For the right term above, upper bound is `ln(n)`

Hence, complexity of this code is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Your answer is clearer, honestly, especially because you factored out `n` and made the terms that sum up to `log_e(n)` clear.

Answer (score 1):

The inner loop runs from `2` up to but not including `n/i` times. You can express it as `n/i - 2`.

If we run the inner loop `n - 2` times (since that's the number of times the outer loop runs), we get the following summation:

```
(n/2 - 2) + (n/3 - 2) + ... + (3 - 2)
```

I have a hunch but can't remember 100% that this series sums up to `log_e(n) * n` or similar. So in terms of time complexity, this becomes `O(log n * n)`.

Comment: For calculating complexity, as a general rule, I just ignore constants and just look at the order of magnitude for the number of iterations. That makes it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The loop exits as soon as i * j ≥ n, i.e. when j = ceiling(n / i) ~ n / i. As it starts from j=2, the number of iterations is ceiling(n / i) - 1.